# How to disable context menu for smartphones and tablets?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I seen quite a number of JavaScript and jQuery codes online to disable right click and context menu but unfortunately they do not work on mobile devices, any advise on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because on smartphones and tablets these are no mouse events but touch events. Look for a way to detect and if needed disable touch events.